# Installing invoke on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, python

I am using `Centos7` on `Linux` server and was trying to install invoke.

```
[xyz@innolx20122 sd-test]$ sudo pip install invoke
[sudo] password for xyz:
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting invoke
  Downloading invoke-1.4.1-py2-none-any.whl (208 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 208 kB 260 kB/s
Installing collected packages: invoke
Successfully installed invoke-1.4.1
```

nothing is displaying when ran "`rpm -qa | grep invoke`"

also below command is failing with issues

invoke --list

Comment: `rpm` is the Redhat Package Manager. You didn't use that to install `invoke` - you used `pip`. Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "_failing with issues_"

Comment: The command to see packages installed with `pip` is `pip list` or `pip freeze`.

Comment: Running `sudo pip install ...` is very prone to system breakage. [Read here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/do-not-run-pip-as-root) for details. Never install things that way in CentOS/RHEL.

Comment: Thanks all for such a good pointers